# SQL server - create report via command line

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server management studio to generate reports and save them as PDF files.
from the instance going to "management" --> "data collection" --> right clicking it and going to "reports" --> "server activity history".
Then I'm selecting the date range, and exporting this report as PDF file.

My question is:
how can I do this via windows command line?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can visit creating reports through command line: [Create Reports through Command Line](https://docs.devart.com/studio-for-sql-server/writing-data-reports/creating-report-with-cmd.html)